# grep|sort and display only the first line

Tags: sorting, grep

I am trying to grep for a pattern and sort by a column and display only the first line by using the following command:

```
grep "BEST SCORE" Result.txt | sort -nk 4 | "display only first line"
```

I don't want to save the `grep` neither the`sort` result into a file.

Answer (score 11):

```
grep "BEST SCORE" Result.txt|sort -nk 4|head -1
```